# DropDownlist selected value - MVC 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a problem with selected value in View, the item shown is the default value on Edit, not the correct value of the object.

```
  public List<Interop.GcpBE750.GcpBECondPagamento> GetAll(){....}
```

Edit Method :

```
  BSCondPagamento ctlCondPag = new BSCondPagamento(p);
  CondPag = new SelectList(ctlCondPag.GetAll(), "CondPag", Descricao",Cliente.get_CondPag());
```

View Class:

```
 <span class="span-editor">Modo Pag.</span>
 @Html.DropDownList("ModoPag", Model.ModoPag, "Seleccione o Modo de Pagamento")
```

What i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the Name of the DropDownlist and starts work..... still don't know why.